# Option value not submitting to MySQL database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an html form that is submitting data to a MySQL database using `$_POST`. All of the data is submitting properly except my `<option>` fields. The database fails the submission when I try to use these. When I do a `print_r` the values are correct, however, they are not being submitted. Thank you for any help you can afford. Here is the code: The `center/center_location` is the one giving me the problem.

PHP

```
<?php

    include('php/functions.php');

    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass, $dbname);
    //Test database connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Database connection failed: " .
            mysqli_connect_errno() .
            " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO rehab ".
            "(name, center, first_name, initial, last_name, insurance, street1, street2, city, state, zip, contact, tel1, tel2. , callback_time)".
            "VALUES ('$name', '$center_location', '$referral_first_name', '$referral_middle_initial', '$referral_last_name', '$insurance','$referral_street1', '$referral_street2', '$referral_city', '$referral_state', '$referral_zip', '$referral_contact', '$referral_email', '$referral_tel1', '$referral_tel2', '$callback_time')";//
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if($result){

    }else{
       die("Database query failed." . mysql_error() . " " . mysqli_connect_error($db));
    }
?>
```

This is from my functions.php file...

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "password";
    $dbname = "tc_referral";

    //Set form variables
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
    $center_location = isset($_POST['center_location']) ? $_POST['center_location'] : "";
    $referral_first_name = isset($_POST['referral_first_name']) ? $_POST['referral_first_name'] : "";
    $referral_middle_initial = isset($_POST['referral_middle_initial']) ? $_POST['referral_middle_initial'] : "";
    $referral_last_name = isset($_POST['referral_last_name']) ? $_POST['referral_last_name'] : "";
    $insurance = isset($_POST['insurance']) ? $_POST['insurance'] : "";
    $referral_street1 = isset($_POST['referral_street1']) ? $_POST['referral_street1'] : "";
    $referral_street2 = isset($_POST['referral_street2']) ? $_POST['referral_street2'] : "";
    $referral_city = isset($_POST['referral_city']) ? $_POST['referral_city'] : "";
    $referral_state = isset($_POST['referral_state']) ? $_POST['referral_state'] : "";
    $referral_zip = isset($_POST['referral_zip']) ? $_POST['referral_zip'] : "";
    $referral_contact = isset($_POST['referral_contact']) ? $_POST['referral_contact'] : "";
    $referral_email = isset($_POST['referral_email']) ? $_POST['referral_email'] : "";
    $referral_tel1 = isset($_POST['referral_tel1']) ? $_POST['referral_tel1'] : "";
    $referral_tel2 = isset($_POST['referral_tel2']) ? $_POST['referral_tel2'] : "";
    $callback_time = isset($_POST['callback_time']) ? $_POST['callback_time'] : "";


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if($insurance == "yes"){
            $message = "<span style=\"color: #0054a6;\">Your form has been submitted. Thank you!</span>";
        }else {
            $message = "They must have insurance to be submitted.";
        }
    }else {
        $message = "<span style=\"color: #0054a6;\">Please submit the form.</span>";
    }

$center_location = "

    <option value=\"1\">Central Florida Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"2\">Columbus Girls' Home</option>
    <option value=\"3\">Columbus Women's Home</option>
    <option value=\"4\">Hosanna House</option>
    <option value=\"5\">Jacksonville Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"6\">Kansas City Girls' Home</option>
    <option value=\"7\">Lakeland Girls' Home</option>
    <option value=\"8\">Macon Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"9\">Middle Georgia Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"10\">Ozarks Boys' Ranch</option>
    <option value=\"11\">Pensacola Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"12\">Pensacola Women's Center</option>
    <option value=\"13\">Prayer Mountain Boys' Academy</option>
    <option value=\"14\">South Florida Davie Women's Home</option>
    <option value=\"15\">Southwest Florida Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"16\">Southwest Florida Women's Home</option>
    <option value=\"17\">Tallahassee Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"18\">Vero Beach Boys' Ranch</option>
    <option value=\"19\">West Florida Boys' Ranch</option>
    <option value=\"20\">Western Kentucky Men's Center</option>";
```

And the HTML...

```
<div id="form">
        <form action="referral_form.php" method="POST" name="rehab_referral" id="rehab_referral">
            <div id="section_header"><h1>Center Information</h1></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" autofocus required></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Center Location:</label><select id="center_location" name="center_location" required>
                    <option><?php echo $center_location; ?></option>

                </select>
            </div>
                <br>
            <div id="section_header"><h1>Referral Information</h1></div>
            <div class="block"><h2>Prospect's Info</h2></div>
            <div class="block"><label>First Name:</label><input type="text" id="referral_first_name" name="referral_first_name" required></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Middle Initial:</label><input class="middle_initial" type="text" id="referral_middle_initial" name="referral_middle_initial" width="1" maxlength="1"></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="referral_last_name" name="referral_last_name" required></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Do they have insurance?</label><select name="insurance" id="insurance">
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="block"><h2>Address</h2></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Street 1:</label><input type="text" id="referral_street1" name="referral_street1"></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Street 2:</label><input type="text" id="referral_street2" name="referral_street2"></div>
            <div class="block"><label>City:</label><input type="text" id="referral_city" name="referral_city"></div>
            <div class="block"><label>State:</label><select id="referral_state" name="referral_state">
                    <option><?php echo $states; ?></option>   
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="block"><label>Zip: </label><input type="number" id="referral_zip" name="referral_zip" maxlength="5"></div>
            <div class="block"><h2>Contact Info</h2></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Contact Name: </label><input type="text" id="referral_contact" name="referral_contact" required></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Email Address: </label><input type="email" id="referral_email" name="referral_email"></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Phone 1: </label><input type="tel" id="referral_tel1" name="referral_tel1" required></div>
            <div class="block"><label>Phone 2: </label><input type="tel" id="referral_tel2" name="referral_tel2"></div>
            <br>
            <div class="block"><label>Preferred callback time: </label>
                <select name="callback_time" id="callback_time">
                    <?php echo $callTimes; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="block"><a><input type="submit" action="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></a><?php echo $message; ?></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: i tested it now, its sending the value of the center_location
 [center_location] => 2

are you sure you are getting it from the $_POST['center_location']?

Comment: I get the same thing and this is what is confusing me. Now, if I echo the variable `$center_location` it list all of the options.

Comment: echo the query and lets see it.

Comment: @IdanMagled I posted a screenshot...

Comment: The table structure would help too

Comment: @TomToms Just posted it. Thank you for the help. I have tried it as `INT` and `NOT NULL`, but neither have worked.

Comment: tel2 is null but you aren't allowing it to be null in your database for one, same for street2. More generally your insert query doesn't insert all the infos, you do not seem to insert everything after city.

Comment: I do not insert everything because I was troubleshooting the issue. I knew that one of the values was giving me an issue, so I commented out the rest to narrow it down. That is how I found out it was my `<option>` elements that was giving me the issue.

Comment: Honestly I don't see why it would be an issue and as your other fields do not accept null commenting them out will make the query fail every time. I think you are misinterpreting the error message you are getting

Comment: try this INSERT INTO rehab (name, center, first_name, initial, last_name, insurance, street1, street2, city, state, zip, contact, email, tel1, tel2, callback_time) VALUES ('aaa', '3', 'aaaa', 'd', 'aaaa', 'yes','aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'AZ', '36584', 'aaa', 'aaa', '011121', '00011', '1')

Comment: Show us your full html.

Comment: @Petah You can see all of the code now.

Comment: @TomToms It works when I manually `INSERT` those values. I replace your values with my variables and it fails. Definitely something wrong with my variables and I am certain that it is all of the `<options>` tags.

Comment: No your array output shows that the same exact value I put in my query is passed. Try uncommenting every field and passing data for all fields (echo your query to make sure). Make sure you are sending at the very least every field that is not marked as allowed to be null (except auto incremented id of course).

Comment: On a side-note as insurance is a yes/no answer you should really use a boolean. But that is not what is causing the error

Comment: @TomToms I have tried that to no avail. When I uncomment everything, I get `Database query failed` output on the page, per my PHP. Something is failing.

Comment: Those lines which you just added in your edit $center_location = "

    <option value=\"1\">Central Florida Men's Center</option>
    <option value=\"2\">Columbus Girls' Home</option> [...] are overwritting $center_location so it is probably not getting the proper value now

Comment: @TomToms I understand that it may not be getting the proper value, but it will not submit anything to the database. Even if the field is set to `TEXT` it still does not work. As we can see the `$_POST` seems to be passing the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm going to rewrite the code 'cause it will be easier that way. But to be bluntly honest you need way more help than we can provide using stack overflow and there might be a couple errors and surely are lots of bad practices still in there (like using a varchar for yes/no).

functions.php

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "password";
    $dbname = "tc_referral";

    //Set form variables
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
    $center_location = isset($_POST['center_location']) ? $_POST['center_location'] : "";
    $referral_first_name = isset($_POST['referral_first_name']) ? $_POST['referral_first_name'] : "";
    $referral_middle_initial = isset($_POST['referral_middle_initial']) ? $_POST['referral_middle_initial'] : "";
    $referral_last_name = isset($_POST['referral_last_name']) ? $_POST['referral_last_name'] : "";
    $insurance = isset($_POST['insurance']) ? $_POST['insurance'] : "";
    $referral_street1 = isset($_POST['referral_street1']) ? $_POST['referral_street1'] : "";
    $referral_street2 = isset($_POST['referral_street2']) ? $_POST['referral_street2'] : "";
    $referral_city = isset($_POST['referral_city']) ? $_POST['referral_city'] : "";
    $referral_state = isset($_POST['referral_state']) ? $_POST['referral_state'] : "";
    $referral_zip = isset($_POST['referral_zip']) ? $_POST['referral_zip'] : "";
    $referral_contact = isset($_POST['referral_contact']) ? $_POST['referral_contact'] : "";
    $referral_email = isset($_POST['referral_email']) ? $_POST['referral_email'] : "";
    $referral_tel1 = isset($_POST['referral_tel1']) ? $_POST['referral_tel1'] : "";
    $referral_tel2 = isset($_POST['referral_tel2']) ? $_POST['referral_tel2'] : "";
    $callback_time = isset($_POST['callback_time']) ? $_POST['callback_time'] : "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if($insurance == "yes"){
        $message = "<span style='color: #0054a6;'>Your form has been submitted. Thank you!</span>";
    }else {
        $message = "They must have insurance to be submitted.";
    }
}else {
    $message = "<span style='color: #0054a6;'>Please submit the form.</span>";
}
```

referral_form.php

```
    require_once('php/functions.php');

    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass, $dbname);
    //Test database connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Database connection failed: " .
            mysqli_connect_errno() .
            " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO rehab ".
            "(name, center, first_name, initial, last_name, insurance, street1, street2, city, state, zip, contact, tel1, tel2, callback_time)".
            "VALUES ('$name', '$center_location', '$referral_first_name', '$referral_middle_initial', '$referral_last_name', '$insurance','$referral_street1', '$referral_street2', '$referral_city', '$referral_state', '$referral_zip', '$referral_contact', '$referral_email', '$referral_tel1', '$referral_tel2', '$callback_time')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if($result){

    }else{
       die("Database query failed." . mysql_error() . " " . mysqli_connect_error($db));
    }
?>
```

html file

```
   <div id="form">
            <form action="referral_form.php" method="POST" name="rehab_referral" id="rehab_referral">
                <div id="section_header"><h1>Center Information</h1></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" autofocus required></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Center Location:</label><select id="center_location" name="center_location" required>
<option value="1">Central Florida Men's Center</option>
    <option value="2">Columbus Girls' Home</option>
    <option value="3">Columbus Women's Home</option>
    <option value="4">Hosanna House</option>
    <option value="5">Jacksonville Men's Center</option>
    <option value="6">Kansas City Girls' Home</option>
    <option value="7">Lakeland Girls' Home</option>
    <option value="8">Macon Men's Center</option>
    <option value="9">Middle Georgia Men's Center</option>
    <option value="10">Ozarks Boys' Ranch</option>
    <option value="11">Pensacola Men's Center</option>
    <option value="12">Pensacola Women's Center</option>
    <option value="13">Prayer Mountain Boys' Academy</option>
    <option value="14">South Florida Davie Women's Home</option>
    <option value="15">Southwest Florida Men's Center</option>
    <option value="16">Southwest Florida Women's Home</option>
    <option value="17">Tallahassee Men's Center</option>
    <option value="18">Vero Beach Boys' Ranch</option>
    <option value="19">West Florida Boys' Ranch</option>
    <option value="20">Western Kentucky Men's Center</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                    <br>
                <div id="section_header"><h1>Referral Information</h1></div>
                <div class="block"><h2>Prospect's Info</h2></div>
                <div class="block"><label>First Name:</label><input type="text" id="referral_first_name" name="referral_first_name" required></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Middle Initial:</label><input class="middle_initial" type="text" id="referral_middle_initial" name="referral_middle_initial" width="1" maxlength="1"></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="referral_last_name" name="referral_last_name" required></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Do they have insurance?</label><select name="insurance" id="insurance">
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="block"><h2>Address</h2></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Street 1:</label><input type="text" id="referral_street1" name="referral_street1"></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Street 2:</label><input type="text" id="referral_street2" name="referral_street2"></div>
                <div class="block"><label>City:</label><input type="text" id="referral_city" name="referral_city"></div>
                <div class="block"><label>State:</label><select id="referral_state" name="referral_state">
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>  
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="block"><label>Zip: </label><input type="number" id="referral_zip" name="referral_zip" maxlength="5"></div>
                <div class="block"><h2>Contact Info</h2></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Contact Name: </label><input type="text" id="referral_contact" name="referral_contact" required></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Email Address: </label><input type="email" id="referral_email" name="referral_email"></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Phone 1: </label><input type="tel" id="referral_tel1" name="referral_tel1" required></div>
                <div class="block"><label>Phone 2: </label><input type="tel" id="referral_tel2" name="referral_tel2"></div>
                <br>
                <div class="block"><label>Preferred callback time: </label>
                    <select name="callback_time" id="callback_time">
                    <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
                    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="block"><a><input type="submit" action="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></a><?php echo $message; ?></div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So, what did you change? I understand bad practices, but that does not always mean that it will not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep but I like to point it out (especially the boolean !!) as it will help you write better code. So it works now ? I just changed around your code a bit as I had indicated in my previous comments, comparing it with your old code should give you a good idea. Please upvote & accept the answer if solved that's the best thanks you can give us ;)

Comment: I just tried the code that you provided and the same thing is happening.